# Swift - saving values from a thread to a variable

Tags: ios, swift

I have new, empty 2 variables:

```
var hallOfFame = ""
var hallOfFameGrupy = ""
```

and 2 threads:

```
func downloadRankingPersonal(adress : String, adress2 : String, completed: @escaping () -> ()){
    let url = URL(string: adress)
    let idGry = self.wybranaGra!.id!
    print("Startuje 1 wątek")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            var statusRanking = ""
            do {
                Alamofire.request(adress, method: .get, parameters: nil)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        let jsonResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)
                        if (jsonResponse["stanyGry"][0]["email"].string == "" || jsonResponse["stanyGry"][0]["email"].string == nil){
                            statusRanking = "0"
                        } else{
                            statusRanking = jsonResponse["stanyGry"][0]["email"].string!
                            self.hallOfFame = statusRanking
                        }
                    }
                    .responseString { response in
                        if let error = response.result.error {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        if let value = response.result.value {
                            print(value)
                        }
                }


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.hallOfFame = statusRanking
                    self.downloadRankingGroup(adress: adress2){
                    }

                    completed()
                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON ERROR")
                self.hallOfFame = ""
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}

func downloadRankingGroup(adress : String, completed: @escaping () -> ()){
    let url = URL(string: adress)
    let idGry = self.wybranaGra!.id!
    print("Startuje 2 wątek")
    print("adress 2: \(adress)")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            var statusRanking = ""
            do {
                Alamofire.request(adress, method: .get, parameters: nil)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        let jsonResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)

                        let grupy = jsonResponse["ranking"]["grupy"].array
                        if (grupy!.count > 0) {
                            statusRanking = "1"
                            self.hallOfFameGrupy = statusRanking
                            print("ilosc rekordow: \(grupy!.count)")
                        } else {
                            statusRanking = "0"
                        }


                    }
                    .responseString { response in
                        if let error = response.result.error {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        if let value = response.result.value {
                            print(value)
                        }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.hallOfFameGrupy = statusRanking
                    if(self.hallOfFame != "" && self.hallOfFameGrupy != "") {
                        self.checkCodeRankingAlert()
                    }
                    completed()
                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON ERROR")
                self.hallOfFameGrupy = ""
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

After running these two threads, I would like to complete the following variables: hallOfFame and hallOfFameGrupy.

Unfortunately, the above code starts correctly, downloads data through Alamofire, but does not save the downloaded data to variables. These variables are empty.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Please help me:)

Comment: I'm wondering why do you load data with `URLSession` and then also with `Alamofire`? The returned `data` of the `dataTask` is not used at all.

Comment: yes I know. This is my "debug". I have tested if downloaded data from the internet is certainly downloaded correctly. The data is downloaded correctly. I just do not know why the threads do not write the downloaded values to variables

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with how you filled `hallOfFame` or `hallOfFameGrupy` but with the `statusRanking`. When using closures, variables are **copied** inside the closure and are not sent by reference (because `String` is value, if it was an Object, it would get mutated). You're changing statusRanking only inside the Alamofire Closure. `statusRanking` started with `""` and was copied inside the Alamofire clsoure with `""` value, you mutated it locally. and furthoer on, you have another closure `DispatchQueue.main.async` which also copies the `statusRanking` and it's value is still `""`. 
Move your `DispatchQueue.main.async` code inside the Alamofire Closure when you want to actually mutate `hallOfFame` and it will work.

#### Important

Using a class to use in this case (so your mutations would apply) is not gonna work either. because there's no guarantee that your second Closure `DispatchQueue.main.async` will be ran after Alamofire Closure get's called. based on speed it MIGHT work sometimes, but your rate of success is below 1%.